# Differing units in linear regression

Tags: regression

Let's assume we have the following simple linear regression equation:

```
y = 10 - 4.2x
```

Let's further assume that our response variable `y` is **expressed in units of 100 kilograms**.  Let's also assume that our independent variable `x` is expressed in currency.

Is it correct to say that for every 1-unit change in currency `x`, that our `y` response variable will *decrease* by 420 kilograms?

Comment: Yes, the inference from regression is scale invariant meaning the predicted response line will be the same whether the units are transformed *before* the response is input the regression model, or if the predictions are transformed *after* fitting the regression model.

Comment: @AdamO please see my answer on what I think OP should change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost correct to interpret the regression coefficients this way. Instead of saying "for every 1-unit change" there is a decrease, it should be: "For every 1-unit increase in currency" there is a decrease. Specifying the direction of the relationship is important for readers.

A more pedantically correct way to interpret these coefficient relationships would be:

*"For every one unit increase in currency, the expected y decreases by 420 kgs. For every one unit decrease in currency, the expected y increases by 420 kgs."*